# What is it exactly? Error: vendor.camera.aux.packagelist

Tags: android-camerax

Currently trying out the new CameraX. Anyone know what's the problem. I should have all the permissions needed.

Here is my entire logcat.

```
2019-12-08 03:57:56.716 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:56.717 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:56.717 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:56.717 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:56.718 11667-11696/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:56.718 11667-11696/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:56.759 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.192 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.215 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.239 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.242 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.542 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.552 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.556 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
2019-12-08 03:57:57.557 11667-11667/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.585 11667-11708/com.example.camerax E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
2019-12-08 03:57:57.891 11667-11708/com.example.camerax E/Camera: Unable to open camera 0 due to CAMERA_DISABLED (1): validateClientPermissionsLocked:928: Caller "com.example.camerax" (PID 10280, UID 11667) cannot open camera "0" from background
2019-12-08 03:57:57.899 11667-11708/com.example.camerax E/Camera: CameraDevice.onError(): 0 with error: ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED
2019-12-08 03:57:57.901 11667-11708/com.example.camerax E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-
    Process: com.example.camerax, PID: 11667
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: onError() should not be possible from state: INITIALIZED
        at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera$StateCallback.onError(Camera.java:850)
        at androidx.camera.core.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onError(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:120)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$8.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

It clearly tries a lot, then gives up.
Given the complete lack of posts both here and on Google about it, I'm going to give you all my code.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.camerax">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.camerax"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

```
package com.example.login3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraX;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisConfig;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureConfig;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
import androidx.camera.core.PreviewConfig;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Rational;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10; //arbitrary number, can be changed accordingly
    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}; //array w/ permissions from manifest
    private TextureView txView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);


        txView = v.findViewById(R.id.view_finder);

        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            startCamera(); //start camera if permission has been granted by user
        } else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
        return v;
    }

    private void startCamera() {

        //make sure there isn't another camera instance running before starting
        CameraX.unbindAll();

        /* start preview */
        int aspRatioW = txView.getWidth(); //get width of screen
        int aspRatioH = txView.getHeight(); //get height
        Rational asp = new Rational (aspRatioW, aspRatioH); //aspect ratio
        Size screen = new Size(aspRatioW, aspRatioH); //size of the screen

        //config obj for preview/viewfinder thingy.
        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(asp).setTargetResolution(screen).build();
        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig); //lets build it

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
                    //to update the surface texture we have to destroy it first, then re-add it
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output){
                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) txView.getParent();
                        parent.removeView(txView);
                        parent.addView(txView, 0);

                        txView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                        updateTransform();
                    }
                });

        /* image capture */

        //config obj, selected capture mode
        ImageCaptureConfig imgCapConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
                .setTargetRotation(getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
        final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imgCapConfig);

        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.capture_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                        String msg = "Photo capture succeeded: " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                        String msg = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(cause != null){
                            cause.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //bind to lifecycle:
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, imgCap, preview);
    }

    private void updateTransform(){
        /*
         * compensates the changes in orientation for the viewfinder, bc the rest of the layout stays in portrait mode.
         * methinks :thonk:
         * imgCap does this already, this class can be commented out or be used to optimise the preview
         */
        Matrix mx = new Matrix();
        float w = txView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float h = txView.getMeasuredHeight();

        float centreX = w / 2f; //calc centre of the viewfinder
        float centreY = h / 2f;

        int rotationDgr;
        int rotation = (int)txView.getRotation(); //cast to int bc switches don't like floats

        switch(rotation){ //correct output to account for display rotation
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                rotationDgr = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                rotationDgr = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                rotationDgr = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                rotationDgr = 270;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        mx.postRotate((float)rotationDgr, centreX, centreY);
        txView.setTransform(mx); //apply transformations to textureview
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        //start camera when permissions have been granted otherwise exit app
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
            if(allPermissionsGranted()){
                startCamera();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){
        //check if req permissions have been granted
        for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I even tried implementing the code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56806751/12253594 but that didn't work.

Best regards.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588357/15443504) solution may be help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159083/14085239) answer.
For privacy and security, the camera is not allowed to run in the background